# how to find an index in Arraylist of custom object based on its specific properties in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have an arraylist of event

```
var approvedEvents = ArrayList<Event>()
```

the class of Event is like this

```
class Event() {

    var eventID : String = ""
    var createdBy: String = "" // uid of user creator
    var creatorFullName: String = ""
    var creatorIsVerified : Boolean = false
    var creatorProfilePictureImagePath = ""
    var createdAt : Date = Calendar.getInstance().time
    var hasBeenApproved : Boolean = false
    var title : String = ""
    var speaker : String? = null
    var coordinate : GeoPoint = City.defaultCityCoordinate
    var address : String = ""
    var city : String = ""
    var venue : String = ""

}
```

so I want to find an index in `approvedEvents` arraylist that its eventID match `selectedEvent.eventID` how to do that in Kotlin ? is there specific method that I can use ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `indexOfFirst` or `indexOfLast` to find the index of an item in an `ArrayList` based on your own criteria like below:

```
val index = approvedEvents.indexOfFirst{
        it.eventID == selectedEvent.eventID
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you have to override equals function in your Event class like

```
------
------
var city : String = ""
var venue : String = ""

override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean{
  if(other is Event){
    return eventID.equals(other.eventID)
  }
  return false;
 }
}
```

Now when you want to search for an Event object with eventId in a list, first create a temporary event object with that eventId which you want to search like

```
val temp=Event()
temp.eventID="102"
```

and simply get the index

```
print(events.indexOf(temp))
```

Comment: This will likely break the equality contract and is not needed

Comment: Yes I know, then override the hashCode also :D.  Anyhow I used this way in java project. But as Kotlin provides a much better function like indexOfFirst so recommend to use this instead.